# Location of lock screen

Tags: windows, windows-xp, lock-screen

Does anybody know if it is possible to change a setting so that the Windows XP Lock Screen is not centered, but let's say in right or left top/down corner or maybe even a give x or y coordinate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please note : Only for Advance Users.You may end up reinstalling your OS if not followed this one properly**

These are the steps to do that.

1. Install Recovery Console  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314058/
2. Downolad a copy of ResourceHacker  http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/
3. Find `msgina.dll` under `\windows\system32` and copy it to the root (C:) folder
4. Start ResourceHacker and open msgina.dll from the root
5. Under `Dialog-1900` replace the dialog with this one:

> 1900 DIALOGEX 0, 0, 0, 0  STYLE
>   WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE  CAPTION "" 
>   LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH,
>   SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US  FONT 0, ""  {  }

Hit "Compile Script" and save it (an original of your msgina.dll was saved automatically under C:\ with the name "msgina_original.dll")

Restart the computer and choose Recovery Console at start up

Copy the new .dll into "\windows\system32" and "\windows\system32\dllcache" (hit "y" when it asks for rewriting existing file)

these are the commands:

```
copy c:\msgina.dll c:\windows\system32\ 
copy c:\msgina.dll c:\windows\system32\dllcache
```

type "exit"

Now when your Windows restarted and you Lock your computer there will not be any pop-up window. To unlock just simply hit `ALT+CTRL+DEL`